# Install riscv spike simulator'; Failed to run dtc: No such file or directory Child dtb process failed

Tags: simulator, riscv, spike

I try to install the riscv tool to my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server.

Use the following git repo and follow its build procedure:

1. [spike simulator](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim)
2. [GNU tool](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain) 
   Installation (Newlib)
3. [riscv pk](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-pk)

Issue `spike pk hello`, gives me

> Failed to run dtc: No such file or directory
>   Child dtb process failed

I have already installed the **device-tree-compiler** through apt command.
And checked with `which dtc`, outputs `/usr/bin/dtc`

What might be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

I run those commands on a command-line interface, not capable to run any graphic user interface. Not sure if that causes this problem.

The spike simulator is my first attempt to execute riscv code, I am also welcome to other recommendations.

Comment: Run spike under `strace -f -o log spike pk hello` and check which syscall arguments yield this error.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by creating a symbolic link using `ln -s $(which dtc)` and the problem is solved.